# How to add Marker Dynamically on Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, android-fragments, google-api

I have created and added a Marker in `Google map`, Now i take user location as input, and on basis of user location, i want to add another marker and draw a line in between.

This is what i have done.

```
     //OnCreate()
     mClient= new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).
                addConnectionCallbacks(this).
                addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).
                addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API).enableAutoManage(this, this).build();




        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

     /**
         *
         * @PLACES API
         */


        PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);

        autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
                // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
                Log.i("Place Name", "Place: " + place.getName());
                LatLng latLng = place.getLatLng();
                destinationLat= latLng.latitude;
                destinationLng= latLng.longitude;


                destinationLatLng= new LatLng(destinationLat, destinationLng);
               /* mapFragment.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(destinationLatLng)
                        .title("PAF-KIET"));*/
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Status status) {
                // TODO: Handle the error.
                Log.i("Error", "An error occurred: " + status);
            }
        });

   @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        LatLng pafKietLocation = new LatLng(24.865498, 67.073302);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(pafKietLocation)
                .title("University"));
        googleMap.setMinZoomPreference(14.0f);
        googleMap.setMaxZoomPreference(74.0f);
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(pafKietLocation));

    }
```

The problem is that i am unable to find any way of passing user `LatLng` to the Map.

Comment: "User LatLng", what do you mean?

Comment: @GurgenHakobyan : on `onMapReady`, I am adding a Marker with predefined `Lat Lng` values, Now i want to add a maker on `onPlaceSelected()` as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare `GoogleMap map` in your activity and inside `onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)` add `this.map = googleMap`. And always check for null when use `this.map`. In `onPlaceSelected`

```
if(this.map != null)
{
    this.map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(destinationLatLng)
                    .title("PAF-KIET"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

like Gurgen said , use a global instance of GoogleMap then use it whenever you need it , but first you should get the instance of map in your onCreate() method.